# what's wrong with the prove about "$f \in L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$ implies a.e. point belongs to the Lebesgue set of $f$ "

Tags: real-analysis

Some definitions:

If a measurable function on $\Bbb{R}^d$ is **locally integrable**, if for every ball $B$ the function $f(x)\chi_B(x)$ is integrable. We shall denote by $L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$ the space of all locally integrable functions.

If $f$ is locally integrable on $\Bbb{R}^d$, the **Lebesgue set** of $f$ consists of all points $\bar{x} \in \Bbb{R}^d$ for which $f(\bar{x})$ is finite and $$\lim_{m(B)\rightarrow 0}_{\bar{x}\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)-f(\bar{x})| \, \text{d}y=0$$

---

Theorem:

If $f \in L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$,then for a.e. $x$$$\lim_{m(B)\rightarrow 0}_{x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_Bf(y) \, \text{d}y=f(x)$$

---

Problem:

If $f \in L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$, then almost every point belongs to the Lebesgue set of $f$.

---

My approach to this problem:

By definition, for a fixed $\bar{x}$, $|f(y)-f(\bar{x})| \in L_\mathrm{loc}^1(\Bbb{R}^d)$ as a function of $y$. Then I use the above theorem to this function. I get

$$\lim_{m(B)\rightarrow 0}_{\bar{x}\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)-f(\bar{x})| \, \text{d}y=|f(\bar{x})-f(\bar{x})|=0,$$,

then almost every point belongs to the Lebesgue set of $f$. what's wrong with my prove? thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that for a given $\bar{x}$, $\bar{x}$ is one of the few points for which the limit is *not* zero. Since you are defining different functions for each $\bar{x}$, conceivably this could happen for each $\bar{x}$, in which case no points would be in the Lebesgue set of $f$.

Comment: Thanks very much. And I can't understand the reply. Did you mean choose some $\bar{x} \not\rightarrow 0$ and...  I can only understand only this. The following "defining different functions for each $\bar{x}$ ",which I can't understand.  I am too stupid to understand your reply :( .